# Project won't compile after Android Support Design update

Tags: android, android-support-library

I just updated Android Support Design from v.23.3.0 to v.23.4.0 and now when I try to build the solution, I get the following errors:

```
    C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    76  Yourtime
    Error   12  Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button'.  C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    10  Yourtime
    Error   41  Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat'.  C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    67  Yourtime
    Error   19  Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.  C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    34  Yourtime
    Error   13  Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'.    C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    24  Yourtime
    Error   26  Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'.    C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    44  Yourtime
    Error   32  Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'.    C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    53  Yourtime
    Error   46  Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'.    C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    81  Yourtime
    Error   16  Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle'.   C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    29  Yourtime
    Error   37  Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle'.   C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    61  Yourtime
    Error   9   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.Design.TabLayout'.  C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    5   Yourtime
    C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\obj\Debug\res\drawable-mdpi\prof.png   Yourtime
    Error   17  No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'color'.    C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    30  Yourtime
    Error   38  No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'color'.    C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    64  Yourtime
    Error   20  No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.  C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    39  Yourtime
    Error   27  No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.  C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    50  Yourtime
    Error   33  No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.  C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    58  Yourtime
    Error   42  No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.  C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    71  Yourtime
    Error   47  No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.  C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    82  Yourtime
    Error   14  No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'. C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    25  Yourtime
    Error   21  No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'. C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    37  Yourtime
    Error   28  No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'. C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    48  Yourtime
    Error   34  No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'. C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    56  Yourtime
    Error   43  No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'. C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    69  Yourtime
    Error   22  No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'. C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    38  Yourtime
    Error   29  No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'. C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    49  Yourtime
'tabTextAppearance'.        C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\App6\App6\Resources\values\Styles.xml    47  Yourtime
    Error   25  No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
```

How do I resolve these?

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file please ? I would suggest updating both the `appcompat` and `support.design` to same version. Something like: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'`
and    `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'`

Comment: @ShobhitPuri I was able to resolve it. I was using a wrong reference for the library. Thanks for answering :) I have another issue related to this now. FAB is not visible inside the view. I have created a thread here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005226/floating-action-button-not-showing-when-used-inside-a-fragment can you please take a look?